# how to get Resource and Resource groups Cost information, from azure rest API'S

Tags: azure, rest, api, resources, cost-management

I am using Microsoft azure rest API'S to get Information. I want to get Cost Information for Resources and Resource Groups for that subscription. I tried many apis but didn't work.. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Azure Cost Management Query REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usagebyscope)

Comment: thanks for your reply jack, 
I tried "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usagebyscope#resourcegroupquery"
in response I am getting only two columns UsageDate and Currency... 
how can I get PreTaxCost and ResourceGroup Column also in response.